# Duplicated colorbars when creating an animation

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am new to matplotlib. When I generate a series of contourf plots with a loop, matplotlib creates n duplicated colorbars (the colorbar has a fixed range)

Must I destroy the old colorbar for each loop, if so how do I do that?

Update:

Ok, but if I generate a colorbar for a contourf plot. How do I make sure that the entire extent of the scale is included. I have tried using "clip=False" & extend='both'

```
c_scale = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin=0, vmax=1,clip=False)
cbar = plt.colorbar(cmap=plt.cm.jet,norm=c_scale,shrink=0.5,extend='both')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

contourf does not generate a colorbar, colorbar does.

If the colorbar has a fixed range, you could call colorbar() once at the beginning and then merely plot your new contourf without calling colorbar()

An example:

```
#In which we make contourplots with just one colorbar

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.figure(1)
plt.clf()
plt.contourf(np.random.random((10,10)))
plt.colorbar()
for k in xrange(10):
    plt.contourf(np.random.random((10,10)))
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to continuously update the colorbar and everything else in the figure, use plt.ion() at the very beginning to enable interactive plotting and use a combo of plt.draw() and plt.clf() to continuously update the plot

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.ion(); plt.figure(1);
for k in range(10):
    plt.clf(); plt.subplot(121);
    plt.contourf(np.random.randn(10,10)); plt.colorbar();
    plt.subplot(122,polar=True)
    plt.contourf(np.random.randn(10,10)); plt.colorbar();
    plt.draw();
```

Note that this works with figures containing different subplots and various types of plots (i.e. polar or cartesian)